# GQL query for a "db.ListProperty CONTAINS foo"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

With GQL, it is possible to run a query for entities that have a certain property with a value in some list `foo`.

```
foo = ['a']
bar = MyModel.gql('WHERE bar IN :1', foo).get().bar
bar == 'a'
#False
bar in 'a'
#True
```

What I would like to do is the inverse of this: does the `db.ListProperty`, `barfoo`, contain a value `foobar`?

Something like:

```
foobar = 'a'
barfoo = MyModel.gql('WHERE barfoo CONTAINS :1', foobar).get().barfoo
barfoo == 'a'
#False
'a' in barfoo
#True
```

Is this possible? If not, how can I reasonably efficiently replicate this behaviour?

As an extension, it would be even better if I could see if any one of a list `foo` was in the list property `bar`. e.g. if `bar == ['a', 'b', 'c']` then I could query it against `['a', 'y', 'z']`, and return it because it does match on `'a'`.

Comment: Is your query "is 'a' one of the values in the list", or "do any of the values in the list contain 'a'"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman "Is one of the list items the literal `'a'`"

Comment: It seems to be achieved with `.filter('listproperty', 'singleitem')`, but it is *not* possible to do this "for any in a list", I've only managed that by wrapping in a `for` loop. Still interested if there is a gql query string for this though.

Answer (score 1):

For a search of a literal value inside a repeated property, you just use the normal `=`:

```
MyModel.gql('WHERE barfoo = :1', foobar)
```

And for the "is any of this list in the listproperty", you can use exactly the same IN as your original query. Do note though that IN is generally very inefficient in the GAE datastore.

(Note, there is never any benefit in using GQL over the db/ndb APIs. It can't do anything that those APIs can't do, and in fact the statements are converted to exactly the same underlying remote procedure calls.)

Comment: Oh snap, seriously?! So if `ent.barfoo == [1, 2]` and `foobar == 1` then `ent` is in the result?

Comment: @OllieFord yes. The way I understand it, a repeated entity actually "flattens" your repeated entity in the index table, making multiple  entries (one entry with "ent" and "barfoo = 1" and one entry with "ent" and "barfoo = 2", which lets you query them directly.  Daniel might correct me though

Comment: @Julldar Does that mean if a `db.ListProperty` will have known constant size `x`, it is cheaper to have `x` properties, to avoid duplicating the others - however large `x` is?

Comment: I did not know about repeated entities, interesting. I'll have to read up on that some more.

Comment: @OllieFord IF I understood it correctly, yes. Mind you I may very well be wrong... I would wait for Daniel to come back and confirm what I'm saying.  Although mind if all X properties are indexed, you create 5 extra indexes on every put... so maybe not THAT worth it

Comment: @Julldar is correct as far as indexes are concerned. But there wouldn't be any benefit in using separate properties: you would lose the possibility to query "is 'a' one of the entries". Plus, with a ListProperty, you would only index combinations that actually exist; with separate properties, each combination would have to be indexed.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What I mean is if I have a `db.ListProperty(db.Key)`, and I know the list is of length `x`, and `x` is small. Then it's surely faster to access if the model has `x` `db.ReferenceProperty`s? Then there's only a single entry per entity, instead of `x` entries. Or have I totally misunderstood the workings?